# Error while trying to Build Dense Cloud on Agisoft Metashape for photogrametry

Tags: gis, drone.io, photogrammetry

I am trying to Build Dense Cloud on Agisoft Metashape and I get the following Error:

clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, sizeof(size_t), &binaries_size, NULL):CL_INVALID_BINARY (-42) at line 851

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THSd6.png)

Can somebody help me?

ty!

I tried to build a dense cloud, i expected to happen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is related to GPU driver. If you have several GPUs enabled for the processing, check, which one is raising the error, then update the GPU driver by downloading it from the official web-site.

If you have both discrete and integrated graphics available, leave only discrete GPU enabled for the processing.